# JQM Calendar event struggle

Tags: jquery, html

Hello stackoverflow users!  I have some problems with my JQM calendar.
I have connected it to a webservice to gather info/dates.

However. I dont understand how im suppouse to add more events trough code when a user want to add a new event without coding it in like so:

```
var date = new Date();
var d = date.getDate();
var m = date.getMonth();
var y = date.getFullYear();
$("#calendarr").jqmCalendar({

    events: [{
        "summary": mcnname + mcntime + mcnweeks + mcnDateSplitFirst + mcnDateSplit,
            "begin": new Date(y, m, 14),
            "end": new Date(y, m, 15)
    }, ],
    months: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
    days: ["Su", "Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa"],
    startOfWeek: 0
});
```

What i want to do:

i would like to add events trough code behind in webservice insead of typing them in by code. Please help (and sorry for the bad parsing code :P )

Answer (score 0):

you handle your weather data server side (PHP or whatever you're using) and format the data and pass it to the page. The events for JQM Calendar are in json format, so you need to take your weather data and format to json encode like your event you have hard coded.

Once you have your events set on the server side then on your page you can do something like the following in jquery

```
var weatherEvents = <?php echo $weather_data; ?>;
$("#calendarr").jqmCalendar({

    events: weatherEvents,
    months: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
    days: ["Su", "Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa"],
    startOfWeek: 0
});
```